# Saving a matrix into a MongoDB database

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

       // var Answer = require("mongoose");

        $scope.circles = [
             JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 20, \"r\":15}"),
             /* much more similar entries */
        ];


);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ["app"]);
```

My question is very simple:

I have this AngularJS code for a very simple SPA.

How can I save the array circles on the server-side (inside a database) or more specifically, how can I write the server controller which allows me to do such thing?

Comment: How to you want to use the stored data? Are you asking how the document should be stored? Or are you asking how to write the code from this point to store the document in the database?

Comment: Send it to server using `$http`. You have been told several times that database interaction is only done on server

Comment: @BlakesSeven I want to use the data on a second page, using like a route or something similar so people can change it and save it into the DB. So I was asking how to write the code from this point to store the document in the DB.

Comment: @charlietfl I know that Node, Express, Mongoose and MongoDB all live on the server and Angular lives in the browser. I have understood that. My technical difficulty is how to use the $http to send it to the server, as I've never done anything similar before and all the code I find is hard for me to follow

Comment: `$http.post(url, {circles: $scope.circles})` .. nothing difficult sending it. If you know all the above why is the question about how to insert in database from client side then? Makes the whole question very vague

Comment: Okay. We have discussed this before but you are still not getting the point. Here you have your little block of angular code and some small representation of data you want to store. But asking how to write the controller to receive it and also how to store it in MongoDB with absolutely no explaination of how you want to read or query or otherwise use that data is **too broad a question**. As I said before. 1. Ask a question about writing the server controller, "as it's own question", with the appropriate tags (not angular, not MongoDB). 2. Think about the MongoDB bit and write another question

Comment: @BlakesSeven I have edited my question

Comment: `server` is a worthless tag ... tag with the stack you are using on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm well, on the follow up of the discussion on the comments, would this be a viable way to write the controller to send data to the server:

```
var dbtest = angular.module('dbtest',[]);
var app = angular.module('app', ['dbmodule']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

       // var Answer = require("mongoose");

        $scope.circles = [
             JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 20, \"r\":15}"),
             /* much more similar entries */
        ];



);

dbtest.controller("dbtest",function($http) {
    var app = this;
    //var url=...
    app.SaveAnswer = function (newAnswer) {
        $http.post(url+"/add", {circle:$scope.circles}).success(function () {
            console.log("Success");
        })
    };

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ["app"]);
//maybe another bootstrap is needed... angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('dbtest'), ["dbtest"]);
```

Then for the POST method on the server side, server.js file, I'd add something like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

var Answer = require('../db/db_model');

app.post("/add", function(req, res){
    var resp = req.circles;
    var answer = new Answer({ans: resp});
    answer.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Saved");}
    });
});

//Change this in deployment to port.env or similar
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Port 3000 connected");
});
```

Is something along these lines correct? Then I can use the dbtest controller on the HTML such that when the user clicks a button the matrix is saved into the DB, right?